# iOS Overlay UI on Google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

[image]

The bars at the top and bottom are made with ImageViews, the buttons and the logo are children of a view overlaid onto the mapView as seen here:

[image: My view architecture]

My specific problem is that the MapView is sucking away all touch events so no buttons are working. Ive solved it by enabling user interactions on the view that contains all my overlaid controls but it disables all interactions with the map. I have also tried to wrap the ui around a view that is not user interactable with two subviews (containing the bars) that are, which ends up in weird presentation errors and a lot of NSLog'd constraint errors.

Any ideas on how to properly achieve this layout? The map is not supposed to work if the user tries to interact with it by touching the grey-ish bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a single view that holds all of the overlay elements and it is above the Map View, therefore it will handle all touches and not your Map View.

Based on this design, what I would do is create a view that contains the top section and a view that contains the bottom section. Then, place those in their locations above the Map View, this will make it so that there is no view above the Map View in the middle.

[image]

Here you see, the green section is "Top Overlay" and the purple section is "Bottom Overlay", there is no view covering the mid section of the map view where you want your user to be able to interact with it.

Comment: Do you think this is the only way? Our Android app already behaves the way our design intends it to, so we'd really like to keep it that way on iOS.

Comment: This won't be evident to the user, it's an implementation detail. Why does it matter how it is implemented? Maybe I've misunderstood the issue.

Comment: I am referring to how the map is still visible under the bars, even though the map wont work if you drag there

Comment: So you don't want the map to be visible? In the layout I've suggested the user will not be able to interact with the map when touching the green or purple views.

Comment: I am going to take your route as i see this limitation on the iOS framework and i don't want to work around it myself.

Comment: I am not sure what you feel the limitation is? It seems pretty straightforward to me. You can go with layout you have now but you'd have to forward your touches to the map view which to me seems unnecessary logic when you can lay it out this way.

Comment: The limitation is that views marked as non-interactive don't forward events to their interactive children. This made us compromise the design in the way you exposed in this answer.